# How to retrieve value against key from map

Tags: groovy

I am able to populate a hash map using groovy. How can I now get the corresponding value against a key from that hash map? Please note, I have to pass the key in a variable while doing the lookup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access groovy map by dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283215/access-groovy-map-by-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like:

```
def map = [tim: 'yates']

def key = 'tim'

println map[key]
```

?